# Filtering Sharepoint Dataview using subjoin

Tags: sharepoint, dataview

I have the same question as [Filter/search joined datasource dataview webpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833790/filter-search-joined-datasource-dataview-webpart) which was asked about six months ago.  This must be a common issue.

Since sharepoint basically combines two dataview's when using a joined datasource, I'm unable to filter based on the second dataview (the child). I can filter either rows of the parent or rows of the child. But the child cannot prevent the parent from not displaying particular rows, which I need it to when returning back search results.

My parent table is sql and the child is a Sharepoint list.  My results have been that either it does not filter at all or I get an xslt error.  Can someone help me?

Comment: lolly provide some code xslt snippet.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I was making it too hard.  It was as simple as:

```
[@clientNumber = ../../../Ethical_Screens/Rows/Row/@Title]
```

Another question though. I am trying to filter the dataview web part using the `currentUser` filter. I have confirmed that this works with simple sql queries. It is not working on this more complex SQL query, however. Any thoughts?

Note: No need to use parameters with the `CurrentUser` filter. It automatically filters the page.